# PyGame garbles horizontal pixel line at image load

Tags: python, image, pygame, load, png

I am loading a png file in PyGame which looks fine before I load it.
If you look at the bottom of the image screenshot, a single horizontal pixel line has been distorted. I included the original, and the screenshot. I have tried, smoothscale and normal scale, but nothing seems to make a difference.
Does anyone have some hints for me?
My load code is as follows:

```
palmTree = 'palmTree.png'
palm = pygame.image.load(palmTree).convert_alpha()
palm = pygame.transform.smoothscale(palm, (palmwidth, palmheight))
screen.blit(palm, (x, y))
pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: original palm tree]

[image: screenshot with garbled pixel line]

Thanks for the comments below. I believe the problem I have has nothing to do with my program. I ran another program a friend gave me and bingo ... the same problem. Could it have something to do with my Mac Retina display?

Comment: Have you tried isolating the incident and seeing if the problem persists if the image is blitted without being scaled?

Comment: Can you add the used `import` lines to your post? I'm having troubles replicating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows both the palm tree unaltered as well as scaled down by 10% side by side. I don't see any strange bars with it implemented as I have it.

```
import pygame,sys,math
from pygame.locals import *

def Main():
    pygame.init()
    screen_dimensions = 640,480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_dimensions,0,32)
    unaltered_palm = pygame.image.load("palm.png").convert_alpha()
    palm_rect = unaltered_palm.get_rect()
    scale = palm_rect[2:]
    scale[0],scale[1] =int(math.ceil(scale[0]*.9)),int(math.ceil(scale[1]*.9))
    altered_palm = pygame.transform.smoothscale(unaltered_palm,scale)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.blit(unaltered_palm,(50,125))
        screen.blit (altered_palm,(375,130))
        pygame.display.flip()

Main()
```

[image: running image]